# Как сделать странцу, которая заполняет историю?

Tags: javascript

Я часто видел такие сайты (чаще всего блоги), переходя на которые стрелка "назад" в браузере просто перестаёт работать. Как это можно сделать на JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще на сколько я знаю это не безопасно и браузер не разрешит что либо делать с историей пользователя, но можно осуществлять переход по ссылкам с помощью javascript и тогда она не будет сохранятся в истории браузера, попробуйте вот так сделать:

```js
function link(){   
   window.location.replace('http://google.com');
   return false;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="link()">Go to link</button>
```

Comment: c'mon, а как же history и pushState?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский возможно и есть вариант, я пишу что я знаю как бекенд :) нужно было года 1.5 назад что-то типо такого сделать, может за это время появились варианты, или у нас фронтенды были не очень

Comment: это же просто переадресация, а надо так, чтобы кнопка была кликабильной, но ничего не делала

Comment: @VladGavriuk ну так вы передаете в функцию ссылку и через js делаете редирект на нужную ссылку, для пользователя это будет как простой переход по ссылке, а вот для браузера нет

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan вы правильно говорите, но есть возможностьсделать так, что человек просто напросто заходит на сайт, не на ссылку, свйт ему не понравился, посетитель хочет нажать на кнопку "назад", кликает на кнопку, а она ничего не делает.

Comment: @VladGavriuk вот в чем дело, ну возможно тут и не в js реализация тогда

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan разве другие языки могут так же эффективно работать с браузером, как JavaScript?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61346/discussion-between-vlad-gavriuk-and-yaroslav-molchan).